# How to make Tkinter.Label justify correctly

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am having an issue getting the text inside a label to left justify in Tkinter. I have tried using the justify=Tkconstants.LEFT but that doesn't seem to work. I have also tried anchor=Tkcontants.W but that doesn't seem to help either. The text always appears in the center of the label. Here is what I have regarding the label:

```
LookupOutput = Tkinter.Label(UI,textvariable=User,justify=Tkconstants.LEFT)
LookupOutput.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=5, padx=5)
```

I assume it has something to do with my columnspan but I don't know how to fix it. Does anyone have an idea on how to get this thing to left justify the text?

Comment: The 'User' text variable is just a list of space delimited strings with no newline characters if that helps at all.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where your issue is coming from without the rest of the code but what happens if you were to add `sticky = W` within your `.grid( ... )` arguments?

Comment: see example images on `https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/tree/master/tkinter/grid-pack-align

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to have the text in a label aligned to the left of the widget is with the `anchor` attribute. A value of `"w"` (or by using the Tkinter constant `W`) stands for "west".

```
LookupOutput = Tkinter.Label(UI,textvariable=User,anchor=Tkconstants.W)
```

The `justify` attribute only affects text that wraps.

If that isn't working, the problem might not be with the text in the label. It might be that your label doesn't occupy the space you think it does. An easy way to check this is to give the label a distinctive background color so that you can distinguish the label from its parent.

I notice that you aren't using the `sticky` attribute when you call `grid` -- that may also cause problems. By default grid will align a widget in the center of the space allocated to it. If you want it to "stick" to the left side of the space that was given to it, use `sticky="w"` (or, again, use the Tkinter constant).