# Why is this text not centered when I explicitly make it? (Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I just need to center a ttk Label on the top of my window.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

window = Tk()

Label(master=window, text="Welcome to the funny quiz!!!!!!!!!!!", justify="center").place(x=500, y=0)

window.geometry("1000x600")
window.mainloop()
```

This code yields this:
[Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21P0K.png)
I expected it to be centered

What's the correct way to center it?

Comment: The effect of `justify` option of `Label` will only be shown when there is more than one line of text.  For your case, you need to use `anchor="n"` in `.place(...)`.

Comment: btw, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35368542/4834) states that: `The justify attribute only affects text that wraps.`

Comment: @acw1668
So what if I want to add a Label just below that and center that as well?

Answer (score 0):

Change the number of the x axis accordingly.. Like,

```
Label(master=window, text="Welcome to the funny quiz!!!!!!!!!!!", justify="center").place(x=400, y=0)
```

**Or**

Just simply use pack manager instead.

```
Label(master=window, text="Welcome to the funny quiz!!!!!!!!!!!", justify="center").pack()
```

Comment: How do you know that x=400, y=0 is the center and why wouldn't that be 500,0 instead?

Comment: @RedP It differs accordingly to your screen resolution. 400 will not always be the centre. So, using pack is the best to centre texts(Especially for headers).

Comment: How do I use grid to do that?

Comment: For grid used sticky='ne'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `anchor='n'` to anchor it to north.

```
Label(master=window, text="Welcome to the funny quiz!!!!!!!!!!!").place(x=500, y=0, anchor='n')
```

Also, you can use pack to anchor the text you want to center.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

window = Tk()

label = Label(master=window, text="Welcome to the funny quiz!!!!!!!!!!!")
label.pack(anchor="center")

window.geometry("1000x600")
window.mainloop()
```

Although, I recommend using grid to align your objects to ease up any future items you intend to add.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html

Comment: How would I do that using grid?

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
I just need to center a ttk Label on the top of my window.

Why is this text not centered when I explicitly make it
```

Easier way without using `anchor`. It is better to used `pack()`.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()

ttk.Label(master=window, text="Welcome to the funny quiz!!!!!!!!!!!").pack()

window.geometry("1000x600")
window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]